# How to multipart post form data to LinkedIn using OAuth 1 and DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: dotnetopenauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the DotNetOpenAuth framework which has been great to get up to speed with consuming data.

I'm using it to talk to LinkedIn and am having trouble figuring out the correct approach to posting/sharing information to the site.  Here is the reference I am using - http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api

When I execute the below code I always get the below error responses;

**Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

I am using Oauth v1.0a.

Here is my code;

```
        try
        {
            HttpDeliveryMethods resourceHttpMethod = HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest;

            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><share><comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://bit.ly/cCpeOD</comment>";
            xml += "<content><title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title>";
            xml += "<submitted-url>http://sanfrancisco.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/stories/2010/06/28/daily34.html</submitted-url>";
            xml += "<submitted-image-url>http://images.bizjournals.com/travel/cityscapes/thumbs/sm_sanfrancisco.jpg</submitted-image-url>";
            xml += "</content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";

            var multiparts = new List<MultipartPostPart>();
            MultipartPostPart part = MultipartPostPart.CreateFormPart("body", xml);
            part.PartHeaders[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
            multiparts.Add(part);

            var resourceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares", resourceHttpMethod);
            HttpWebRequest request = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(resourceEndpoint, accessToken, multiparts);
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

            IncomingWebResponse response = consumer.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);
            this.resultsBox.Text = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to write back on this, talking to someone from a vintage google newsgroup I got the direction I needed but wanted to verify the solution before posting.

The big thing I was screwing up on was adding the multipart data prior to sending the request data as opposed to constructing the request myself and writing the new content to the stream.

I'm new to using OAuth and REST so I don't know all the ins and outs, suffice to say I've validated this code against both the LinkedIn and Twitter REST APIs.

Here is the new CODE;

```
        try
        {
            Encoding encoder = Encoding.ASCII;
            HttpDeliveryMethods resourceHttpMethod = HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest;

            byte[] bytes = encoder.GetBytes(xd.OuterXml.ToString());

            var resourceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(ResourceURL, resourceHttpMethod);
            HttpWebRequest request = _consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(resourceEndpoint, _manager.AccessToken);
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";

            using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            IncomingWebResponse response = _consumer.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);

            ret = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _Logger.Error(OpenLogger.FormatException(ex));
        }
```